# VBA code executing very slowly

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2016

I'm new to VBA so the code I've written is very sloppy. My apologies.

The essence of my problem is that I need to delete duplicate rows from a worksheet with approx. 45,000 rows. Each iteration where the row is deleted takes approximately 30 seconds to complete, and I need to do this for thousands of rows. Any suggestions for how to improve my code so that this all goes faster?

```
Sub delete_duplicate_rows()
For i = 1 To 85000
    If ActiveCell <> ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0) Or ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1) <> ActiveCell.Offset(1, -1) Or ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) <> ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1) Or ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2) <> ActiveCell.Offset(1, 2) Or ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3) <> ActiveCell.Offset(1, 3) Or ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4) <> ActiveCell.Offset(1, 4) Or ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5) <> ActiveCell.Offset(1, 5) Or ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6) <> ActiveCell.Offset(1, 6) Or ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7) <> ActiveCell.Offset(1, 7) Or ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8) <> ActiveCell.Offset(1, 8) Or ActiveCell.Offset(0, 9) <> ActiveCell.Offset(1, 9) Or ActiveCell.Offset(0, 10) <> ActiveCell.Offset(1, 10) Or ActiveCell.Offset(0, 11) <> ActiveCell.Offset(1, 11) Or ActiveCell.Offset(0, 12) <> ActiveCell.Offset(1, 12) Or ActiveCell.Offset(0, 13) <> ActiveCell.Offset(1, 13) Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        GoTo NextIteration
    Else
    End If
    If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then Exit Sub
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Range("A1:Q1").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
NextIteration:
    Next i
End Sub
```

Many thanks.

Comment: [Avoid using `.Select`/`.Activate`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: Curious why the "Remove Duplicates" built-in tool under the [Data] Ribbon tab can't be used for this?

Comment: @Comintern the answer below is still making way too many worksheet reads (and hints at nesting yet another loop, which wouln't improve performance). I'd work out the last row, dump the appropriate columns into a 2D array, iterate that array, and `Union` the rows that need to be deleted - then delete all union'd rows in a single `.Delete` operation. I guess MT could be useful if there are millions of rows to go through, but then the MT overhead might just outweight its benefits.. not to mention out-of-process overhead for whatever non-VBA scripting tech is used for this.

Comment: Also see if that rather impressive matching criteria can be worked into a `Range.RemoveDuplicates` call. If so, then you get Excel to do all the hard work.

Comment: A sample of data would be helpful. It appears you are satisfied with only looking a few rows ahead or behind for duplicates? There are many ways to speed this up but by necessity are more complex.

Answer (score 0):

As others said, your code is slow do to a couple of things like using `select`, `activate` and `goto`

I believe the culprit of the slow performance is the multiple condition check at once, as you could check for changes on cells.

```
sub delete_duplicate_rows(byref ws as worksheet)

    ' Dim tbl_width as long, tbl_height as long
    ' Dim row_n, col_n as long
    '
    ' This would be the correct form of one line var declarations, as it was stated in the comments
    ' I prefer this style, so I can group things like iters, table sizes, variants for `For each` 
    ' and save some lines and see more code(I've a small screen)

    dim tbl_width as long 
    dim tbl_height as long
    dim row_n as long 
    dim col_n as long
    with ws
        for row_n=tbl_height to 2 step -1
            for col_n=1 to tbl_width
                if .range(.cells(row_n, col_n)) <> .range(.cells(row_n - 1, col_n)) then
                    .range(.cells(row_n , 1), .cells(row_n, tbl_width)).delete shift:=xlShiftUp
                    col_n = tbl_width
            next col_n
        next row_n
    end with

end sub
```

This doesn't deppends on a fixed set of rows, don't activate or select anything, and the inner loop could be exited before when one of the conditions is not met. This way you will only check enough to make a decision on wheter to delete.

You could nest another loop, so it will check al the rows not just the one below to it.

Comment: note that `dim tbl_width, tbl_height as long` is declaring `tbl_height` as a long integer, and `tbl_weight` remains an implicit `Variant`. Ditto with `row_n`. `ws` has no reason to be passed `ByRef`, too. Lastly, this is still accessing the sheet directly in a tight, nested loop - that'll be faster than OP, but not half as efficient as it could be.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon is this true? Never had a problem with this style of declaration while using `option explicit` you just poked my curiossity and I'm gonna check on that.

Comment: Yup. We even built an inspection for it in [Rubberduck](http://www.github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck) =)

Comment: @Comintern Given, forgot about this.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon You were right! I've been coding this whole time ignoring this implicit `DIM` thing I think I've been trapped in the `c` mentality. Thanks man, I love when stuff like this happens It makes improve your basics.

Comment: We've implemented a couple of inspections in Rubberduck that can help identify quite a lot of the implicit code VBA is running behind your back, and often result in obscure runtime errors that end up on Stack Overflow - like if you forgot the `.` in front of these `Cells` calls, we'd be warning about an implicit reference to `ActiveSheet`; that frequently throws error 1004 and bites someone on SO *every single week* =)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Thanks, mate. I'll be checking that out, VBA seems archaic but it's defo powerfull stuff.